# 1с Получить итоговую сумму по каждому контрогенту

Tags: 1с

```
Запрос = Новый Запрос;
Запрос.Текст = 
    "ВЫБРАТЬ
    |   РеализацияТоваров.Контрагент КАК Контрагент,
    |   РеализацияТоваровТовары.СуммаВсего КАК СуммаВсего,
    |   РеализацияТоваровТовары.Номенклатура,
    |   РеализацияТоваров.ТипЦен
    |ИЗ
    |   Документ.РеализацияТоваров.Товары КАК РеализацияТоваровТовары,
    |   Документ.РеализацияТоваров КАК РеализацияТоваров
    |ГДЕ
    |   РеализацияТоваров.Дата МЕЖДУ &ДатаНачала И &ДатаОкончания
    |   И РеализацияТоваров.Контрагент.ФормаСобственности = &ФормаСобственности
    |ИТОГИ
    |   СУММА(СуммаВсего) 
    |ПО
    |   Контрагент";

Запрос.УстановитьПараметр("ДатаНачала", ДатаНачала);
Запрос.УстановитьПараметр("ДатаОкончания", ДатаОкончания);
Запрос.УстановитьПараметр("ФормаСобственности", ТипКонтрагента);

РезультатЗапроса = Запрос.Выполнить();

ВыборкаКонтрагент = РезультатЗапроса.Выбрать(ОбходРезультатаЗапроса.ПоГруппировкам);

Пока ВыборкаКонтрагент.Следующий() Цикл
    // Вставить обработку выборки ВыборкаКонтрагент

    ВыборкаДетальныеЗаписи = ВыборкаКонтрагент.Выбрать();

    Пока ВыборкаДетальныеЗаписи.Следующий() Цикл
        // Вставить обработку выборки ВыборкаДетальныеЗаписи 

             Область = Макет.ПолучитьОбласть("Область1");
             Область.Параметры.парамвывод = ВыборкаДетальныеЗаписи.СуммаВсего;
             Область.Параметры.контрагент = ВыборкаДетальныеЗаписи.Контрагент;

              ТабДок.Вывести(Область);

    КонецЦикла;
КонецЦикла;
```

у меня выводит сейчас

100   контрагент1

150   контрагент1

10    контрагент1

мне надо чтобы было

260  контрагент1

Ребят помогите пожалуйста!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если ничего не менять, то оставить:

```
Пока ВыборкаКонтрагент.Следующий() Цикл
    // Вставить обработку выборки ВыборкаКонтрагент
    Область = Макет.ПолучитьОбласть("Область1");
    Область.Параметры.парамвывод = ВыборкаКонтрагент.СуммаВсего;
    Область.Параметры.контрагент = ВыборкаКонтрагент.Контрагент;
    ТабДок.Вывести(Область);
КонецЦикла;
```

либо так:

```
Область = Макет.ПолучитьОбласть("Область1");

Запрос = Новый Запрос;
Запрос.Текст = 
"ВЫБРАТЬ
|   Т.Контрагент КАК Контрагент,
|   СУММА(ТабТовары.СуммаВсего) КАК СуммаВсего
|ИЗ
|   Документ.РеализацияТоваровКАК Т
|       ВНУТРЕННЕЕ СОЕДИНЕНИЕ Документ.РеализацияТоваров.Товары КАК ТабТовары
|       ПО (Т.Дата МЕЖДУ &ДатаНачала И &ДатаОкончания
|               И Т.Контрагент.ФормаСобственности = &ФормаСобственности
|               И Т.Ссылка = ТабТовары.Ссылка)
|
|СГРУППИРОВАТЬ ПО
|   Т.Контрагент";

Запрос.УстановитьПараметр("ДатаНачала", ДатаНачала);
Запрос.УстановитьПараметр("ДатаОкончания", ДатаОкончания);
Запрос.УстановитьПараметр("ФормаСобственности", ТипКонтрагента);

РезультатЗапроса = Запрос.Выполнить();
Выборка = РезультатЗапроса.Выбрать();

Пока Выборка .Следующий() Цикл
    Область.Параметры.парамвывод = ВыборкаДетальныеЗаписи.СуммаВсего;
    Область.Параметры.контрагент = ВыборкаДетальныеЗаписи.Контрагент;
    ТабДок.Вывести(Область);
КонецЦикла;
```

Comment: Благодарю дружище!

Comment: @Leshka пожалуйста, отметьте данный ответ как верный